# Samsung Epic Touch 4G - ROM Listing

Tags: custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=HTC_Supersonic/ROMs is a great page for ROM listings for HTC. Is there a similar page out there somewhere listing details on custom ROM's compatible with my Samsung?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of XDA-Dev gives this page: [Rom List Epic 4G Touch](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1288386) last updated yesterday, so it should be up to date.

Comment: Found this one too... much like the one for the HTC:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Epic_4G_Touch/ROMs